# Plus or Minus just before the number

Tags: javascript, html, char

I'm doing my math game and I have problem with char(plus or minus). How can I do it to plus or minus be just before the number? I need to check entered number, I don't want situation for example "--8-88". Problem is in input button with name "minus".

```
<body onload="main_page();">
<form name="game">
    <div style="float: left;" class="screen">
        <input type="text" id="answer" value="" autofocus()>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="-" onclick="game.answer.value += '-'" name="minus">
    <input type="button" value="8" name="eight" onclick="game.answer.value += '8'" >
</form>
```

Comment: please add some use cases. actuall it is not clear, what you want to prevent.

Comment: Just imagine you havent written the question and you wont know your code. Then look at your question and try to understand it.

Comment: You cant check try mach the value using regex, something like this (\+|-)\d

Comment: Now weve got your whole html. Cant you reduce that into a one line [mcve] ?

Answer (score 1):

You are appending the `-` instead of prepending it. You can make it to toggle the minus sign by just taking the numerical value and apply the unary minus operator to it:

```
game.answer.value = -game.answer.value
```

```html
<form name="game">
    <div style="float: left;" class="screen">
        <input type="text" id="answer" value="" autofocus()>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="-" name="minus" 
           onclick="game.answer.value = -game.answer.value">
    <input type="button" value="8" name="eight" onclick="game.answer.value += '8'" >
</form>
```

Please consider using the `script` tag for your JavaScript. Putting more code than this in `onclick` attributes is not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to avoid adding several symbols in front a number and you want your numbers always display whether they are positive/negative. To do this you have to cast them to strings and check whether they already have a '+' or minus '-'. To remove unwanted character you can use regexp:

```
const addPlus = (n) => `+${ n.toString().replace(/[+-]/g, '') }`;
const addMinus = (n) => `-${ n.toString().replace(/[+-]/g, '') }`;
```

You can check a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/oniondomes/n7ytsdy4/